# How to retrieve the same message twice or more in RabbitMQ with php

Tags: php, mysql, rabbitmq

I have some broblems with php + RabbitMQ + MySQL.

I have worker on php, that update one record in DB. Now I trying to make correct 
work if server MySQL gone away.

**What I am doing:**
I'm trying reconnect to DB 10 times, if I can't - need to return this massage back to the RabbitMQ.

For accepting message I use **basic_ack**, for rejecting I use **basic_nack**.

---

**Example:**

```
    if ($can_accept_message) {
        $message->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($message->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);

    } else {
        $message->delivery_info['channel']->basic_nack($message->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
    }
```

But basic_nack delete this message from queue and I can't repeat it again ;(

**Trying like this:** https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/blob/d2b8a292f709b79b1615bef87b1b89bde4c7c347/demo/basic_nack.php

**Reading this:** https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/issues/221

But it still not working.

**What's wrong? Maybe you have any other ideas?**

Comment: can you show us the config of your queue please? And other dummy question, you sure you enter in the `else` ?

Comment: **>> can you show us the config of your queue please?**
Trying like this: https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/blob/d2b8a292f709b79b1615bef87b1b89bde4c7c347/demo/basic_nack.php

**>> And other dummy question, you sure you enter in the else ?**
Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the function basic_nack is defined as follow:

```
/**
 * Rejects one or several received messages
 *
 * @param string $delivery_tag
 * @param bool $multiple
 * @param bool $requeue
 */
public function basic_nack($delivery_tag, $multiple = false, $requeue = false)
```

As you can see, the third parameter is `$requeue = false`

You should try

```
else {
    $message->delivery_info['channel']->basic_nack($message->delivery_info['delivery_tag'], false, true);
}
```

Comment: I tryind write like you say, but it not helps =(
Maybe I need to adding something else?

Comment: Do you process message by message or you process by batch? If you process by batch, the second argument should be `true` too. So to be sure, your  message is deleted from the queue after `basic_nack(...)` right?

Comment: I undestand this, and Yes I am sure.

Comment: You can try, `basic_reject($message->delivery_info['delivery_tag'], true)` instead of `basic_nack()`. It quite the same purpose except `reject` cannot manage batch messages. The `basic_nack` should works, so i doubt the second one do but lets try.

Comment: I don't know why it not helps when I was trying, but I try it again and in works! Thanks a lot!